# Rails create button does not work with render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Following the DRY rule, I've inserted the render partial command inside my `officers\_form.html.erb` view:

```
<%= form_for(officer) do |f| %>
  <% if officer.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(officer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this officer from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% officer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render :partial => 'users/form', :locals => {:user => @officer.user} %>
  <%= render :partial => 'addresses/form', :locals => {:address => @officer.address} %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `users\_form.html.erb` file:

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
  <% if user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :last_name %>
      <%= user_fields.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :first_name %>
      <%= user_fields.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :middle_name %>
      <%= user_fields.text_field :middle_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= user_fields.label :gender %>
      <%= user_fields.select(:gender, User.genders.keys) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <!--div class="actions"-->
    <!--%= f.submit %-->
  <!--/div-->
<% end %>
```

Same reasoning as for User code applies to Addresses code, so I'll omit here for shortness.

This is my `officers_controller` file:

```
class OfficersController < BaseController
  before_action :set_officer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /officers
  # GET /officers.json
  def index
    @officers = Officer.all
  end

  # GET /officers/1
  # GET /officers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /officers/new
  def new
    @officer = Officer.new
  end

  # GET /officers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /officers
  # POST /officers.json
  def create
    @officer = Officer.new(officer_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @officer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @officer, notice: 'Officer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @officer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @officer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /officers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /officers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @officer.update(officer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @officer, notice: 'Officer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @officer }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @officer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /officers/1
  # DELETE /officers/1.json
  def destroy
    @officer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to officers_url, notice: 'Officer was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_officer
      @officer = Officer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def officer_params
      #params.fetch(:officer, {})
      params.require(:officer).permit!
    end
end
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost:3000/officers/new`, the parts included in both the users and addresses forms are shown, but when I press the `Create officer` button nothing happens. Where is the error?

```
class Officer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager#, inverse_of: :officer
  has_many :customers#, inverse_of: :officer

  has_one :user, as: :userable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :address
end

class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :officers#, inverse_of: :manager

  has_one :user, as: :userable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :address, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :address
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: { female: 0, male: 1, undefined: 2 }

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Thanks,
FZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set user_attributes in your officer_params, do this:

```
def officer_params
  #params.fetch(:officer, {})
  params.require(:officer).permit(:id, user_attributes: [:id, :last_name, :middle_name, :first_name, :gender, :_destroy])
end
```

And also change `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :address` 
to

```
 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true'
```

And you need to address_attributes to your officer params aswell but since i don't know your database field i can't do that part for you but it's pretty much the same as the user_attributes but with different fields(except :id and :_destroy which are the same for all).

**EDIT:**

**This is a nested form:**

```
<%= form_for(officer) do |f %>

 <%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %> 
  <%= user.text_field :last_name %>
  <%= user.text_field :middle_name %>
  <%= user.text_field :first_name %>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
  <%= address.text_field :street_name %>
  <%= address.text_field :zip_code %>
 <% end %>

<%= f.submit 'submit' %>
```

This way one submit button supplies for all the nested forms aswell.

**What you have is this:**

```
<%= form_for(officer) do |f %>
 <%= form_for(user) do |f|
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %> // this (f) now stands for the user form instead of the officer form 
   <%= user.text_field :last_name %>
   <%= user.text_field :middle_name %>
   <%= user.text_field :first_name %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>

<%= form_for(address) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %> // same for this one
  <%= address.text_field :street_name %>
  <%= address.text_field :zip_code %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit 'submit' %>
```

Now you don't have a nested form, you just have 3 different full forms and you can't submit multiple forms with one submit button this way.

Comment: This doesn't work, i reflected your suggestions but no luck

Comment: Btw, the first suggestion shouldn't be mandatory, since in my current code I'm permitting everything, while I don't know the goal of your second suggestion...

Comment: What kind of error are you getting, or what is specifically not working? and please show your other controllers and models.. also you don't need to render partials for nested forms. You can just use the f.fields_for part.

Comment: Nothing is broken, but submit command is not run and no record is inserted in the DB. I would like to render them nested because both Officers and Managers have the User and Address objects, so if i don't use the render partial command i would need to clone the fields in each for Officers and Managers. Adding User and Manager model in a bit

Comment: You can still use render but just render the 'f.fields_for' part because now you are putting 2 different forms(address and user) inside the officer form. But since you also render the part '<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>' inside the officer form, the f.fields_for don't work. Because for f.fields_for the f needs to be of the master form, in this case from officer |f| and now it is from user |f| and address |f| and thats not a nested form anymore, so it won't work.

Comment: So you are saying I can't nest forms in this situation? Or maybe I need to rename `<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for(user) do |inneruser| %>`? Can you please provide some code to fix that?

Comment: Wouldn't be fine to remove `<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>` form the user\_form partial? I just tried but I get `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass` highlighting this line of code: `<% if user.errors.any? %>`

Comment: You need to follow all the steps i mentioned earlier aswell as go to your officers_controller.rb new action and add officer.build_user and officer.build_address after the officer = Officer.new (with an @ in front of officer of course.)

Comment: I get `undefined local variable or method 'f' for #<#<Class:0x9b5a0b8>:0x9b59698>` with highlighted the following line `<%= f.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123220/discussion-between-luissimo-and-zanzi).